# Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request'

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, asp.net-web-api, typescript-typings

The **req** variable of **Request** type has no **intellisense** for property **body**. Is this due to the typings?

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { ok, bad } from './responses'

export const signIn: async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
        const { name, pword } = req.body // body is not recognized
        const data = auth.signIn(name, password)
        ok(res, data)
    } catch (error) {
        bad(res, error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) had been removed from [express 4](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x) into separate project,
so there won't be any type definition about it.

I use it this way:

```
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';

let router: Router = express.Router();
router.use(bodyParser.text());

(req: Request, res: Response) => {
    let address = req['body'];
}
```

Comment: i think `bodyParser.json()` - is more common use case.

Comment: yeah, I forgot, req['body'] is same as req.body. but the form req.body is much more js oriented.

Comment: `body-parser` is most certainly still included as a dependency of `express` ~ https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/4.18.2/package.json#L33

Answer (score 1):

i just:

```
npm install @typings/express --save-dev
```

and it gave me the intellisense and allow to recognize 'req.body'.

Comment: Thanks! Knew I was missing something! ;) alternatively `yarn add @types/express`

Answer (score 0):

#### [Solution] Type For Request & Response

You just have to import types like below and it will work

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

...

app.post('/signup', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        const { fullName, email } = req.body;
        ...
    })
);
```

> It didn't work when I did `Express.Request`

#### [Additional] Parsing Request Body

As of express v4.18, you don't need separate package like `body-parser`

You can do like below

```js
import express from 'express';


const app = express();

// Parse request body
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

// Test Route
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.json({ message: 'Hello World' }));
```

Notice that I have put two things above `express.urlencoded` & `express.json` because I found that form data post request was not working with just `express.json`. So keeping both of them parses all kinds of json payload in request to `req.body`

Answer (score 0):

For Node v.20.x this still working

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
```

but VERY important order, middlewares should be BEFORE routes, not after.

Answer (score -2):

I managed to solve it by changing the `package.json` file in development dependencies by adding:

```json
"@types/express": "^4.17.17",
```