# TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'Router'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to start a new enterprise typescript project, and I wanted to work on a good boilerplate, and I found this one : https://github.com/santiq/bulletproof-nodejs.
then I found out some of dependencies are outdated and also some Eslint rules are not applied.
so I tried to update everything and prepare it to start my new projects.
but I get couple of errors.

I get following error in my webstorm :

```
TS2339: Property 'use' does not exist on type 'Router'
```

It draws a red line under some parts of my code.
like :

```js
  app.use('/auth', route);
```

and also following error :

```
TS2339: Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request '.
```

in here :

```js
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      const { debug, error } = Container.get('logger');
      debug('Calling Sign-Up endpoint with body: %o', req.body);
      try {
        const authServiceInstance = Container.get(AuthService);
        const { user, token } = await authServiceInstance.SignUp(req.body as IUserInputDTO);
        return res.status(201).json({ user, token });
      } catch (e) {
        error(' error: %o', e);
        return next(e);
      }
    },
```

and this is my package.json :

```
{
  "name": "bulletproof-nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Bulletproof node.js",
  "main": "src/app.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
    "start": "nodemon",
    "inspect": "nodemon --inspect src/app.ts",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js ",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .ts",
    "lint:js": "npm run lint:eslint src/",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint:js -- --fix"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/santiq/bulletproof-nodejs.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "boilerplay",
    "cron",
    "jobs",
    "js",
    "javascript",
    "typescript",
    "node",
    "express"
  ],
  "author": "Santiago Quinteros",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "agenda": "^3.1.0",
    "agendash": "^1.0.0",
    "argon2": "^0.27.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "celebrate": "^9.1.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "errorhandler": "^1.5.1",
    "event-dispatch": "^0.4.1",
    "eventemitter3": "^3.1.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-basic-auth": "^1.2.0",
    "express-jwt": "^6.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mailgun-js": "^0.22.0",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.7",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "typedi": "^0.8.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/agenda": "^2.0.9",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.8",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.14",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.161",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.36",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "ts-jest": "^24.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/santiq/bulletproof-nodejs/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/santiq/bulletproof-nodejs#readme"
}
```

and finally this is the whole file which gives me error :

```js
import { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { Container } from 'typedi';
import AuthService from '../../services/auth';
import { IUserInputDTO } from '../../interfaces/IUser';
import middlewares from '../middlewares';
import { celebrate, Joi } from 'celebrate';

const route = Router();

export default (app: Router) => {
  app.use('/auth', route);

  route.post(
    '/signup',
    celebrate({
      body: Joi.object({
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        email: Joi.string().required(),
        password: Joi.string().required(),
      }),
    }),
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      const { debug, error } = Container.get('logger');
      debug('Calling Sign-Up endpoint with body: %o', req.body);
      try {
        const authServiceInstance = Container.get(AuthService);
        const { user, token } = await authServiceInstance.SignUp(req.body as IUserInputDTO);
        return res.status(201).json({ user, token });
      } catch (e) {
        error(' error: %o', e);
        return next(e);
      }
    },
  );

  route.post(
    '/signin',
    celebrate({
      body: Joi.object({
        email: Joi.string().required(),
        password: Joi.string().required(),
      }),
    }),
    async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
      const { debug, error } = Container.get('logger');
      debug('Calling Sign-In endpoint with body: %o', req.body);
      try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const authServiceInstance = Container.get(AuthService);
        const { user, token } = await authServiceInstance.SignIn(email, password);
        return res.json({ user, token }).status(200);
      } catch (e) {
        error(' error: %o', e);
        return next(e);
      }
    },
  );

  /**
   * @TODO Let's leave this as a place holder for now
   * The reason for a logout route could be deleting a 'push notification token'
   * so the device stops receiving push notifications after logout.
   *
   * Another use case for advance/enterprise apps, you can store a record of the jwt token
   * emitted for the session and add it to a black list.
   * It's really annoying to develop that but if you had to, please use Redis as your data store
   */
  route.post('/logout', middlewares.isAuth, (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { debug, error } = Container.get('logger');
    debug('Calling Sign-Out endpoint with body: %o', req.body);
    try {
      //@TODO AuthService.Logout(req.user) do some clever stuff
      return res.status(200).end();
    } catch (e) {
      error(' error %o', e);
      return next(e);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Does something like this helps for issue 2 ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325366/property-body-does-not-exist-on-type-request For the number one you should show what's your code

Comment: Could you provide the app and and request imports? This would likely help us to understand the issue

Comment: @Axnyff I guess doing what is said in that question eliminates the main reason of typescript.
It simply says user array style to access object properties.

Comment: @user3252327 I added the file completely .

Comment: I think the type of app should be Application, not router

Comment: @Axnyff That was the first thing came to my mind and I tried, but no help :).
I don't know maybe there is a bug in express types package.
I downgraded this package and it didn't work.
maybe I should downgrade express itself.